# C programming: A pyramid with asterisks

Tags: c, function, printing

What am I doing right? I am trying to learn a function.

This should be like this output:

```
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
```

**My code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void pyramid (int n)
{
    int width = 0;

    if ( n )
    {
        ++width;
        pyramid( f, n - 1 );

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 2 * n - 1; i++ )
        {
            fprintf( f, "%*c", i == 0 ? width : 1, '*' );
        }

        fputc( '\n', f );
        --width;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf ("usage: h4 <number>\n");
        return 1;
    }
    pyramid (atoi (argv[1]));

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 4
    void pyramid (int n) {
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is this problem? Please help me and explain. Thank you. I'm deaf C programmer beginner.

Comment: Wait...are you using C or Python here?  The code looks C, but the error message seems to be from Python.

Comment: Assuming your code is in a file named prog.c you should do 1) compile the program using `gcc -Wall prog.c -o prog` and 2) run the program using `./prog` (note: but first you need to fix the problems reported by the compiler)

Comment: @Devin Morlan as 4386427 mentioned above you have to compile the file using "gcc -Wall prog.c -o prog"  and fix all the errors.

Comment: You will also want to test `if (n > 0)` not just `if (n)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, they're the same when I compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to approach outputting the pyramid (centered) would be to use the *field width* modifier for your `printf` *format string* for the *padding* rather than the fill character itself. Then you can simply loop outputting the number of characters needed per line (which increases by `2` each line, e.g. `1, 3, 5, ...`).

For example, taking the number of lines of output as the first argument to your program, (or using `4` by default if no argument is given), you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FILL '*'

void pyramid (int n)
{
    if (n < 1)              /* validate positive value */
        return;

    int l = 1,              /* initial length of fill chars */
        max = n * 2 - 1,    /* max number of fill chars */
        pad = max / 2;      /* initial padding to center */

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {       /* loop for each line */
        if (pad)                        /* if pad remains */
            printf ("%*s", pad--, " "); /* output pad spaces */
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++)     /* output fill chars */
            putchar (FILL);
        putchar ('\n');                 /* output newline */
        l += 2;             /* increment fill by 2 */
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int n = argc > 1 ? (int)strtol (argv[1], NULL, 0) : 4;

    pyramid (n);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** you can use `unsigned` types throughout to insure positive values, or you can simply validate you have positive values. You should also include `errno.h` and validate the `strtol` conversion, though it will return `0` if no digits are provided)

It also helps to `#define` your fill character at the top of the code, so you have a convenient place for change should you want another character. It prevents digging through your function to find the constant later on.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/pyramidtop 1
*

$ ./bin/pyramidtop 5
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********

$ ./bin/pyramidtop 10
         *
        ***
       *****
      *******
     *********
    ***********
   *************
  ***************
 *****************
*******************
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file is a C file, try to compile it with `gcc`, not executing it with `python`

---

And you have some `f` variable that is not declared used, you can correct this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void pyramid (FILE *f, int n) {
    int width = 0;

    if ( n )
    {
        ++width;
        pyramid(f, n - 1 );

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 2 * n - 1; i++ )
        {
            fprintf( f, "%*c", i == 0 ? width : 1, '*' );
        }

        fputc( '\n', f );

        --width;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf ("usage: h4 <number>\n");
        return 1;
    }
    pyramid (stdout, atoi (argv[1]));

    return 0;
}
```

---

Will give

```
*
***
*****
```

---

Your code can be updated to add spaces before stars and simplified:

1. Use clear variable names (`stars` instead of `n`)
   2. Do not use `fprintf` where a simple `fputc` is enough
2. One variable is used to count stars, use one other to count spaces.

Will this consideration, your code should look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* use clear variable names */
void pyramid (FILE *f, int stars, int spaces) {

    if ( stars>0 )
    {
        pyramid(f, stars -2, spaces + 1  );
        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < spaces; i++ )
        {
            /* use fputc when enough */
            fputc(' ', f );
        }

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < stars; i++ )
        {
            fputc('*', f );
        }

        fputc( '\n', f );

    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf ("usage: h4 <number>\n");
        return 1;
    }
    pyramid (stdout, atoi (argv[1]), 0);

    return 0;
}
```

It gives:

```
   *
  ***
 *****
```

Comment: How can I put spaces pyramid?

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding for a minute how you seem to be running it with `python`, you are recursively calling the funtion here:

```
pyramid( f, n - 1 );
```

However, you only have it defined with one parameter, not with two.

Also, `f` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a much shorter, simpler version, using the formatting features of `printf`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int height = 15;
    char s[2*height-1];
    memset(s,'*',2*height-1);

    for(int i = 0; i<height; ++i)
    {
        printf("%*.*s\n", height+i,2*i+1,s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 9424KB
              *
             ***
            *****
           *******
          *********
         ***********
        *************
       ***************
      *****************
     *******************
    *********************
   ***********************
  *************************
 ***************************
*****************************
```